# Error hresult 0x80070005 when trying to launch a c++ application from visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a new project from an `Ogre3d` template using Visual Studio 2012. Yesterday everything was working fine using the same template but today I'm getting this error no matter what I try:

```
hresult 0x80070005 Access Denied.
```

It's just a simple application built locally. Also when I'm trying to create new project or template it prompts me to connect to Microsoft Team Foundation Server, a thing that was not there before... I'm using `Win 7`.

Anyone has a fix for this?

Thanks!

Comment: "Also when I'm trying to create new project or template it prompts me to connect to Microsoft Team Foundation Server" - maybe you have checked "Add to source control" checkbox in "New project" dialog box.

Comment: Nope didn't fix it ...